# How to clear a String after I turn off a checkbox

Tags: java, jtextarea

I am working on a project that needs check boxes that count.
When you turn one on it adds a word to a String, but when I turn it off, it adds another String that is the same.
e.g.

```
    private javax.swing.JTextArea area;
    public String value = "telephone number is 5";
    private void boxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

    value = value + "\n" + "coke";
    area.setText(value);

}
```

It should print:

```
telephone number is 5
coke
```

Which is does but if I un-ticked it again it prints

```
telephone number is 5
coke
coke
```

because each time I tick the box it adds another "coke" to the "value"

please help me

Comment: What exactly do you expect? The code `value = value + "\n" + "coke";` will indeed append `coke` for each click. If you tell us what you want, we can probably suggest you a solution ;-)

Comment: It keeps adding the same words to the string, so i need it so when the checkbox is off it doesn't add the word but if its on it will need to add the word

Comment: @OtsWng You have to check the status of the checkbox. When it is checked you can add the word. When it is not checked you clear the value. It is just a simple `if(...) { ... } else { ... }` statement.

Comment: why not put that as a answer? I need to get my vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the state of the `checkbox` and only add the text when it is is selected.

Assuming you have somewhere a reference to the checkbox, this should work:

```
private javax.swing.JTextArea area;
private javax.swing.JCheckBox checkBox;

public String value = "telephone number is 5";

private void boxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    if (checkBox.isSelected()) {
        value = value + "\n" + "coke";
        area.setText(value);
    }

}
```

If you only want to show `coke` when the checkbox is selected, and hide `coke` when it is not, use this:

```
if (checkBox.isSelected()) {
    area.setText(value + "\n" + "coke");
} else {
    area.setText(value);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a variable with the name `checkBox` in your code. I added that assuming you should have something like that, but of course there is no way for me to know for sure. Look in the code for your `JTextBox` variable, and that's the one to use...

Comment: but if i make a mistake and want to untick it, it stills print the same thing out again, shall is store what i want to say in a string

Comment: You really have to describe more clearly what exactly it is that you want. Maybe you just want to add the string `coke` once?

Comment: could i use `if(!checkBox.isSelected(){}`if i wanted to make it so when it **isnt** selected?

Comment: Probably you could... I added something to my answer, does that do what you want?

Comment: it does but jtext area is incomparable to string

Comment: You maybe want to use `area.getText()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try if this Works:

```
private javax.swing.JTextArea area;
public String value = "telephone number is 5";
public boolean checked = false;
private void boxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    if(checked){
        checked = false;
    }else{
        value = value + "\n" + "coke";
        area.setText(value);
        checked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You better directly check the state of the checkbox instead of keeping track of a variable...

Comment: Yes this would be better but i dont't know the exact Syntax for this Right Now

Comment: it kept on adding the same thing